# Can not start Vue UI after updating Node and dev-dependencies

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

After updating Node to the latest version I have trouble to start `vue ui`. First it was some dev-dependencies. After setting the latest versions for these dependencies now I get

```
andreas@andreas-X230:/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/projectA$ vue ui
  Starting GUI...
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/projectB/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/locales'
[...]
```

Can someone help me out? It's confusing it is looking for a file in another project (note the different paths to `projectA` and `projectB`.)

Comment: Remove and re-install Vue GUI.

Comment: It's been a while... I assume this was installed globally. Do you have the package name? Or does it come with `@vue/cli@4.5.8`

Comment: `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli` and then `npm i -g @vue/cli`. The latest version is 5.0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall and re-install the vue/cli.

1. `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`
2. `npm install -g @vue/cli`